# Is it possible to test NAT Type in a web page only (possibly using WebRTC)?

Tags: webrtc

I'm new to WebRTC and I noticed that the Web API can request a STUN server for the local public IP, and may set up an RTCDataChannel session with others.

From my understanding, using the APIs above with a Web Server and a WebRTC server, it is possible to check the local NAT type within a webpage.

But as far as I know, all existing NAT Type Checking utilities are binary tools (either command-line or standalone GUI app), so I wonder if there is such a website providing this NAT Type Checking function, or is there any technical difficulty in implementing this? (Or just nobody did this for now?)

Comment: You could more or less implement the STUN Behavior test with two separate peerconnection objects against two different STUN IPs and ports and some other tweaks to the webrtc API.  But what you do with this information?  Either you are able to connect to the remote peer or not. If you need high reliability against restrictive or symmetric NAT environments, use TURN.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Yes, that is pretty much what I thought, and I think it can be used for diagnosis purposes (for example, to test whether the current network support p2p gaming, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://webrtchacks.com/symmetric-nat/
describes an approach. However (speaking as the person who wrote it) why bother? The NAT type doesn't offer you useful information if you use WebRTC (and hence ICE) in the browser.

Comment: Thanks, I read the post before and I'm indeed considering adding a WebRTC server further, such that a user can distinguish the type of Full Cone NAT. I think such a tool can help with debugging the network.